# Array vs List in recursive F# function

Tags: arrays, list, optimization, f#

I have this function:

```
let calculate (candles: CandleData list) : decimal list =
    let inline range (q: CandleData) = q.High - q.Low
    let inline price (q: CandleData) = range q / 2m + q.Low

    let rec update (candles: CandleData list) (output: decimal list) lastPrice priceTracker rangeTracker stateTracker lambda =
        match candles with
        | [] -> output
        | h::t ->
            let priceTracker' = 0.2m * (price h - lastPrice) + 0.8m * priceTracker
            let rangeTracker' = 0.1m * (range h) + 0.8m * rangeTracker
            let lambda        = if rangeTracker <> 0m then abs(priceTracker / rangeTracker) else lambda
            let sqr           = decimal (sqrt (double (lambda * lambda * lambda * lambda + 16m * lambda * lambda)))
            let alpha         = (-lambda * lambda + sqr) / 8m
            let stateTracker' = alpha * price h + (1m - alpha) * stateTracker
            update t (output @ [decimal stateTracker']) (price h) priceTracker' rangeTracker' stateTracker' lambda

    update candles [] (price candles.Head) 0m (range candles.Head) (price candles.Head) 0.01m
```

It operates on lists, but I was wondering if it wouldn't make sense to use an array instead since the data originally comes as an array so I have to convert it to a list to then walk through it sequentially, like an array.

But if I convert it to an array, wouldn't the head / tail part recreate the array every time? so then should I keep the array whole and just iterate with the index?

Comment: In fact the `update` function as stated is inefficient because it appends new elements to the output (`output @ [...]`). It would be more efficient if it added elements at the head `... :: output` and then inverted the list.

Comment: Also, feel free to use a loop with mutable variables. There is nothing wrong with that, as long as mutable values are kept within a simple function and not shared with other parts of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid the cost of converting to `list` and still keep this as idiomatic F#, you can [`scan`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#scan) the original array instead of recursing:

```ml
let calculate (candles : _[]) =
    let inline range (q: CandleData) = q.High - q.Low
    let inline price (q: CandleData) = range q / 2m + q.Low

    let init = price candles.[0], 0m, range candles.[0], price candles.[0], 0.01m
    (init, candles)
        ||> Seq.scan (fun (lastPrice, priceTracker, rangeTracker, stateTracker, lambda) candle ->
            let priceTracker' = 0.2m * (price candle - lastPrice) + 0.8m * priceTracker
            let rangeTracker' = 0.1m * (range candle) + 0.8m * rangeTracker
            let lambda        = if rangeTracker <> 0m then abs(priceTracker / rangeTracker) else lambda
            let sqr           = decimal (sqrt (double (lambda * lambda * lambda * lambda + 16m * lambda * lambda)))
            let alpha         = (-lambda * lambda + sqr) / 8m
            let stateTracker' = alpha * price candle + (1m - alpha) * stateTracker
            price candle, priceTracker', rangeTracker', stateTracker', lambda)
        |> Seq.map (fun (lastPrice, priceTracker, rangeTracker, stateTracker, lambda) ->
            stateTracker)
        |> Seq.skip 1
        |> Seq.toArray
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `mapFold`:

```
let calculate3 (candles : _[]) =
    let inline range (q: CandleData) = q.High - q.Low
    let inline price (q: CandleData) = range q / 2m + q.Low

    let init = price candles.[0], 0m, range candles.[0], price candles.[0], 0.01m
    (init, candles)
    ||> Array.mapFold (fun (lastPrice, priceTracker, rangeTracker, stateTracker, lambda) candle ->
            let priceTracker' = 0.2m * (price candle - lastPrice) + 0.8m * priceTracker
            let rangeTracker' = 0.1m * (range candle) + 0.8m * rangeTracker
            let lambda        = if rangeTracker <> 0m then abs(priceTracker / rangeTracker) else lambda
            let sqr           = decimal (sqrt (double (lambda * lambda * lambda * lambda + 16m * lambda * lambda)))
            let alpha         = (-lambda * lambda + sqr) / 8m
            let stateTracker' = alpha * price candle + (1m - alpha) * stateTracker
            stateTracker, (price candle, priceTracker', rangeTracker', stateTracker', lambda) )
    |> fst
```

It works similar to `scan` but produces an Array simultaneously.

Comment: I never used mapFold, I will read about it; thanks!